# UDIM file name conventions

Tags: texturing, uv

Can someone clarify what is the accepted file name convention for UDIMS for 2024

1. FILENAME_1001
2. 1001_FILENAME
3. FILENAME.1001
4. 1001.FILENAME

or some variation thereof... or do any of these work?

Comment: According to https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/uv/workflows/udims.html#file-substitution-tokens all four variants can work. It depends where you have the special token *<UDIM>* in the filename.

Comment: All of them should work, don't forget the file extension